# Error in deviance residual calculation in R

Tags: r

I estimated a random coefficient discrete-time hazard model with the following command:

```
(logit.model <-
   glmer(event ~ 
       a1
     + a2
     + a3
     + a4
     + high * I(a5 - 2)
     + midup * I(a5 - 2)    
     + obsnum1 + obsnum2 + obsnum3
     + (1 + obsnum1 + obsnum2 + obsnum3 | country_cluster),
     family=binomial("logit"), data=data.final, 
     verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=400)))
```

Now I would like to calculate the deviance residuals by using the following command:

```
    data.final.r <- cbind(data.final,
                          dev.res = residuals(logit.model,
                                              type="deviance"))
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error command:

"$ operator not defined for this S4 class".

Does anyone knows, where the errror could come from, how it can be solved or how the deviance residuals can be calculated alternatively?

Any help would be appreciated very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the version of `lme4` you are using. You can check the version you have with:

```
packageVersion("lme4")
```

Is this a stable version you got from CRAN, then get the latest using `update.packages()` or `install.package(lme4)`)

Is it a development version, which seems to be the case, then get the latest development release using:

```
install.packages("lme4",repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos")
```

Warning: if you were using a stable/CRAN version, changing to the development release may break stuff in your code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the answer, this seemed actually to be the problem. Now I have got a follow up question. Unfortunately, the no. of observation in the estimated model is smaller than the original data set. Therefore I get the error message: "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7041, 6621." Do you know any elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess this has something to do with the `na.action` parameter of `glmer`, which is `na.omit` by default. Check `?na.exclude`.